# Best Practice how to fetch data initially and update it later on using React Hooks etc.?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

There exist a lot of exmaples how to fetch data in functions using custom hooks. In my scenario I'm using the react async hook library (but it could be any other similar hook) and I fetch data (in my example a list of teams) initially. When this list is empty, I show a button which provides the means to create some teams by triggering a backend request. Within this request the now created teams are returned and I want to show them.
This looks like this (very simplified):

```jsx
import {useAsync} from "react-async-hook";
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import { fetchTeams, generateTeams } from 'somewhere';
import TeamsList from 'somewhere';

const Teams = () => {

  const asyncResult = useAsync(fetchTeams); // Async backend request
  const [teams, setTeams] = useState(); // This is my workaround...

  useEffect(() => {
    if (asyncResult.loading === false && asyncResult.result && asyncResult.result.teams) {
      setTeams(asyncResult.result.teams); // This is how I try to react when the fetchTeams promise is resolved...
    }
  }, [asyncResult.loading, asyncResult.result]);

  const handleGenerateTeams = async () => {
    const teamGenerationResult = await generateTeams(); // Async backend request
    setTeams(teamGenerationResult.teams);
  };

  if (asyncResult.loading || (!asyncResult.error && !teams)) { return <div>Loading</div>; }
  if (asyncResult.error) { return <div>{asyncResult.error.message}</div>; }

  const teamsNotExisting = teams.length === 0;

  return (
    { teamsNotExisting && <button onClick={handleGenerateTeams}>Generate</button> }
    <TeamsList teams={teams} /> 
  );
};
```

This is how I ended up to deal with this use case.... but I am wondering if this is really a good solution?
Most examples which are using custom hooks just fetch data and pass it directly for rendering. But this is not sufficient for me, due to I have my click handler which may also generate the data (if not yet existing)... this is the reason why I introduced the teams-state.

So, one other basic question: Is this the way to pass the results from an async fetch hook into my own state?

I know that one answer to my whole question would probably be Redux. But I often read, that Redux might not be needed after all, and for my application I'm quite happy for now without Redux....

Comment: your solution looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, good to hear, because I was really wondering if I am just going into a wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think `react-async-hook` is a pretty good library to handle tasks related to asynchronous, by its pretty hight starred on Github, weekly downloads, so I think somehow its core was implemented with best practice.

So, our job is to implement our business logic or our specific use-case here with "Best Practice", so I think the "Best Practice" here is about how we're confident and happy in our code, and others who will read, or maintain this code in future is also happy. So I think I can help you with a little refactor it as below:

```
import {useAsync, useAsyncCallback} from "react-async-hook";
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {fetchTeams, generateTeams} from 'somewhere';
import TeamsList from 'somewhere';

const Teams = () => {
  const {result, loading, error} = useAsync(fetchTeams);
  const {execute, result: generatedTeamsResult} = useAsyncCallback(generateTeams);
  
  const handleGenerateTeams = () => {
    execute();
  };

  if (loading) { return <div>Loading</div>; }
  if (error) { return <div>{error.message}</div>; }
    
  const shouldGenerateTeam = !result && !result.teams;
  const teams = result && result.teams ? result.teams : generatedTeamsResult.teams;
  return (
    {shouldGenerateTeam && <button onClick={handleGenerateTeams}>Generate</button>}
    {/* Should validate data and avoid passing null or undefined */}
    {teams && <TeamsList teams={teams || []} />}
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi Trung, Thanks for your helpful reply!
I see, this would indeed also be a possible solution, and this avoids the hassle with useEffect.
Just out of interest: Suppose I want to put the results of an async hook (like react async hook) in a state variable: Is the solution I wrote with useEffect a good one, or exist there better solutions?

Comment: Hi Clemens, Your solution is ok, it's not bad practices because sometimes I also use `setState` in a `useEffect`, but the word `effect` I think it is about `side-effect` and Ideally we should keep everything pure as JavaScript's principles